# NSIndexPath 2 indicies

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm doing something that involves a collection view with photos in it, and upon selecting one of the cells, it will segue into a new view where it shows a larger image.

Heres prepare for segue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhotoSegue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *ip = [self.photoCollectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
        PhotoDisplayViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        Photo* photo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:ip];
        NSLog(@"setting PHOTO at indexPath %@", ip);
        [viewController setPhoto:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:photo.url]];
    }

}
```

And heres didSelectItemAtIndexPath

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *identifier = @"showPhotoSegue";
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:self];
    NSLog(@"Selected item at %@", indexPath);
}
```

My view is always empty so i added the print line statements, and it seems the output is always something like

```
Selected cell at <NSIndexPath 0x1e084940> 2 indexes [0, 0], detail view controller
```

So my question is, why is NSIndexPath always a pair of 2 indicies, and also how do i use it in my prepareforsegue to set the view for the segue

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `prepareForSegue:sender:`, you expect `sender` to be a `UICollectionViewCell`.

In `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, you are passing `self` (your `UICollectionViewDelegate`) as the `sender` argument.  I suspect your collection view delegate is *not* a collection view cell.

Instead of sending the collection view delegate as `sender`, and expecting to receive a cell as `sender`, why not pass the index path as `sender` and expect to receive it as `sender`?

```
static NSString const *kShowPhotoSegueIdentifier = @"showPhotoSegue";

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kShowPhotoSegueIdentifier sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kShowPhotoSegueIdentifier]) {
        [self prepareForShowPhotoSegue:segue withIndexPath:sender];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForShowPhotoSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoDisplayViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    Photo* photo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [viewController setPhoto:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:photo.url]];
}
```

Comment: I didnt know you can do that, i was under the assumption maybe some code uses the UICollectionViewCell passed in as sender to do something. 
let me try that

Answer (score 0):

`NSIndexPath` is a file structure that is used to represent directory trees. In the context of a table (indexPathForCell:) it contains a section & row index.

> Each index in an index path represents the index into an array of
>   children from one node in the tree to another, deeper, node. For
>   example, the index path 1.4.3.2 specifies the path shown in Figure 1.

More information [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

NSIndexPath is Mainly used for UITableView Where It will Consider Section as well as Row for That..

so Where ever you want to use NSIndexPath you will be able to access
row and section for that..

so i request you to use indexpath.row for your indexing variable,
if indexpath.section is not useful for you..